# For (Lebesgue) measurable functions $f$ and $g$, if $f=g$ a.e., then $ \int_{E} f=\int_{E} g. $

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Problem**

> Let $f$ and $g$ be bounded (Lebesgue) measurable functions defined on a set $E$ of finite measure. If $f=g$ a.e., then
>   $$
> \int_{E} f=\int_{E} g.
> $$

**Attempt**

> Let $f,g:E\to \mathbb{R}$ be a (Lebesgue) measurable function with $m(E)<\infty$. Assume $f=g$ a.e. on $E$. It is enough to show that
>   $$
> \int_{E} f-g=0.
> $$
>   Let $\varphi$, $\psi$ be simple functions with $\varphi \leq f-g \leq \psi$. Since $f-g=0$ a.e., we have $\psi \geq 0$ a.e. and $\varphi\leq 0$ a.e.. Then, 
>   $$
> 0 \leq \int_{E} \psi {\rm ~and~} 0\geq \int_{E} \varphi,
> $$
>   ${\it whence} $
>   $$
> \int_{E} f-g \geq 0 {\rm ~and~} \int_{E} f-g \leq 0,
> $$
>   as required.

**Question**

1. The hypothesis that there is a simple function $\varphi$ is vaild?
2. What is the exact meaning of 'whence' which is italics?
3. For the end of sentence, what did the right expression of the two?: a.e. or a.e..

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assertion about the simple functions is not clear neither justified. A simpler approach: let $A:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)-g(x)=0\}$, then $A$ is measurable and

$$
\int_{E}(f-g) \mathop{}\!d \lambda =\int_{E \cap A}(f-g) \mathop{}\!d \lambda +\int_{E \cap A^\complement }(f-g) \mathop{}\!d \lambda =\int_{E \cap A}0 \mathop{}\!d \lambda+0=0
$$

where we used the fact that if a set $B$ have measure zero then $\int_B f \mathop{}\!d \lambda =0$ for any measurable function $f$.

Comment: Is there a difference between $dx$ and $d\lambda$? I used $dx$. I'm sorry to confuse you.

Comment: @himath well, the expression $dx$ can be used also in the integral of Riemann so the use of $d\lambda$ make clear that we are using the integral of Lebesgue. It is common to use $d\lambda$ to avoid the use of $f(x)$ in the integrand, that is, it leads to a shorter notation. However you can use also $dx$. It depends on the context when a notation is more useful than the other. Indeed if the context is clear you can just write $\int f$ to represent the same that $\int_E f d\lambda$ of $\int_E f(x) dx$